# Why is $0≠Log(e^{i2n\pi})=i(2n\pi)$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

$\\Log$ denotes the multi-valued natural log defined over the complex numbers

I know that $Log(z)$ is multivalued and that we can choose a particular branch if we want to, but why isn't it the case that $Log(-1)=Log(1/(-1))=-Log(-1) ⟹Log(-1)=0⟹(\theta/\pi)Log(e^{i\pi})=Log(e^{i\theta})=0⟹Log(z)=\ln(|z|)$

Choosing the principal branch, $i\pi=Log(-1)=Log(1/(-1))=-Log(-1)=-i\pi$
. I've never understood why we're allowed to choose a branch even though a contradiction like this can be derived.

Edit: I've understood what I was misunderstanding before. Of course, the rules for the single valued logarithm are not applicable for numbers that are not an element of the positive reals. My mistake

Comment: What is $\ln$, what is $Log$ and why is $\ln (\frac   1a)=-\ln a$?

Comment: ln(x) is the single-valued function allowing a real input greater than zero; it follows from the exponent rule for the single-valued logarithm that ln(1/a)=-ln(a). Log(z) is formally defined as the multi-valued function ln(|z|)+i(arg(z)+2n*pi). What I'm wondering is whether that formal definition for Log in some sense makes less sense than the alternative I presented, Log(z)=ln(|z|)

Comment: My guess is that it's incorrect to use the exponent rule for logarithms when the input is not a positive real number?

Comment: I would not alternate between ln, log, Log, etc. I don't really understand what you're doing or what you're asking, but I would start with knowing that $\log(z) = \ln|z| + i\arg(z)$. For example, the principal branch of log is commonly defined as $\operatorname{Log}(z) = \ln|z| + i\arg(z)$ where $\arg(z) \in (-\pi, \pi]$. Sometimes you would see $\operatorname{Arg}$ instead of $\arg$. Trying to leverage logarithm properties from the real numbers we're used to from grade school (if you live in the United States at least) doesn't always work depending on what interval you define your $\arg$ on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principal branch logarithm is *not* a homomorphism: in general $\log(zw) \not= \log z + \log w$ for nonzero complex numbers $z$ and $w$ off the negative real axis, so all of your experience about "rules" of logarithms is generally *wrong* when you start using numbers outside the positive real axis inside the logarithm function. That means the calculations in your post are mostly nonsense.

If you make incorrect calculations, then it's not surprising that you are reaching "contradictions". There is in fact no contradiction because your premises are just not true. The error you are making is due to implicitly treating the valid equation $\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$ for positive real $x$ and $y$ as if it holds in general for nonzero complex $x$ and $y$, which is a mistake.

We learn in school that for *positive* real numbers, $a^2 = b^2 \Longrightarrow a = b$. If someone then comes along and says "what about $3^2 = (-3)^2 \Longrightarrow 3 = -3$?"  Well, that's just an incorrect conclusion since it is based on a property that *nobody* ever said was true about nonzero real numbers; it true for  positive real numbers, and if your go ahead and use it in a wider setting without checking whether it in fact holds there, you could potentially get nonsense, which is indeed what happens.

Comment: If anything, what I've shown (via proof by contradiction) is that the rules of logarithms cannot be extended to complex numbers. By presupposing that the rules of logarithms can be extended, you can derive contradictions, thereby showing that the presupposition must be incorrect. Would I be correct to say this?

Comment: We can define $\log z = \int_1^z dw/w$ for $z \not\in (-\infty,0]$, with the integral being taken along any path of integration from $1$ to $z$ that does not cross the negative real axis. This is an analytic function of $z$ when $z \not\in (-\infty,0]$ and $e^{\log z} = z$.  We actually do have $\log(zw) = \log z + \log w$ when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers *close* to $1$, but things start going off the rails as $z$ or $w$ get too far from $1$.

Comment: interesting. I'll have to brush up on complex analysis

Comment: There is nothing sacrosanct about the "principal branch".  You could take any crazy path (a "cut") $C$ from $0$ out to the point at $\infty$ and define a logarithm function on the complement of $C$  as $\log z = b + \int_a^z dw/w$ where $a$ is a point off of $C$ and $e^b = a$.  This function of $z$ is analytic off of $C$ and $e^{\log z} = z$ just as before.  When $a = 1$ I was able to use $b  = 0$ since $e^0 = 1$.  But when $a \not= 1$ you can't choose $b = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Then
$Log(\frac w{w^2})=Log(w^2)=-\frac{2\pi i}3\tag1$
But
$Log(w)-Log(w^2)=\frac{4\pi i}3\tag2$
Division rules fails for principal branch of logarithm function defined on $\Bbb C-\{0\}$.

Furthermore, I think we choose $Log(-1)=\pi i$ value in the definition of $Log$, so $Log(-1)\neq -Log(-1)$.